# How to initialize let property of closure type to pointer to some method?

Tags: swift, initialization, closures

Have a look on following code

```
class Example {
    let action: String -> ()

    init() {
        action = method //error: Variable self.action used before initialized
    }

    func method(s: String) {
        println(s)
    }
}
```

I am setting property of closure type to a class method. To reference class method I need to have the single properties initialized but to have it properly inicialized I need to reference that method. How do I get out of the cycle?

I know I can do something like

```
init() {
    action = {_ in }
    action = method //error: Variable self.action used before initialized
}
```

but that just is not nice.

The actual thing I need to do is more complex and makes much more sense bt this is the essence.

Answer (score 5):

You can declare the property as implicitly unwrapped optional:

```
let action: (String -> ())!
```

That's one of the few cases when implicitly unwrapped are useful and can be safely used.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `lazy var` as such:

[image]

The first time you access `action` the expression `self.method` will be evaluated (and by that time `self` is valid).

If you are uncomfortable with `var action` being settable, you can use (a common Apple pattern) of:

```
lazy private var _action : (String) -> () = self.method
var action { return _action }   // only the 'getter' thus `var` is actually `let`
```

and if you are uncomfortable with even these two, you can use `private(set)` to ensure that no setter is visible.  And thus,

```
class Example {
  lazy private(set) var action: (String -()) = self.method

  func method (s:String) { println (s) }
}
```

Comment: This came to my mind as one of the firs options. I consider it worse then changing the value if property twice in constructor (see question) because it makes `action` mutable (`var` instead of `let`) which is less safe.

Comment: You can use `private(set)`, a newer addition to Swift.